# I cannot get my animations to play I am Using slick2d and a SpriteSheet 64 by 64

Tags: animation, slick2d, sprite-sheet

I am using slick2d I have come across this problem where I cannot get this sprite sheet to animate at all I have tried most of the methods using the update function.

```
package javagame;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState{


    Image worldMap;
    boolean quit = false;
    int[] duration = {200,200};
    float monsterPositionX = 0;
    float monsterPositionY = 0;
    float shiftX =  monsterPositionX +320;
    float shiftY =  monsterPositionY +160;

    public Image monsterImage = null;
    public SpriteSheet monsterSheet;
    public Animation monster;
    public Animation monsterAnimationDown;
    public Animation monsterAnimationUp;
    public Animation monsterAnimationLeft;
    public Animation monsterAnimationRight;

    public Play(int state){

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)throws SlickException{
        monsterImage = new Image("/res/Monster.png");
        monsterSheet = new SpriteSheet(monsterImage, 64 , 64);

        monsterAnimationUp = new Animation(monsterSheet, 0,8,8,8,true,200,false);
        monsterAnimationLeft = new Animation(monsterSheet, 0,9,8,9,true,200,false);
        monsterAnimationDown = new Animation(monsterSheet, 0,10,8,10,true,200,false);
        monsterAnimationRight = new Animation(monsterSheet, 0,11,8,11,true,200,false);
        monster = monsterAnimationDown;

    }
    //renders images to screen0
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)throws SlickException{

        monster.draw(shiftX,shiftY);

        if(quit == true){
            g.drawString("Resume (R)", 250, 100);
            g.drawString("Main Menu (M)", 250, 150);
            g.drawString("Quit Game (Q)", 250, 200);
            if(quit == false){
                g.clear();
            }
        }


    }
    // changes translations of game objects
    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException{

        Input input = gc.getInput();
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)){
            monster = monsterAnimationUp;
            monster.setPingPong(true);
            monsterPositionY  += delta *.1f;
        }else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)){
            monster = monsterAnimationDown;
            monsterPositionY  -= delta *.1f;
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){
            monster = monsterAnimationRight;
            monsterPositionX  += delta *.1f;
        }else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){
            monster = monsterAnimationLeft;
            monsterPositionX  -= delta *.1f;
        }


        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)&& input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){
            monster = monsterAnimationUp;
            monster.setPingPong(true);
            monsterPositionY  += delta *.1f;
            monsterPositionX  += delta *.1f;
        }if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)&& input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){
            monster = monsterAnimationUp;
            monster.setPingPong(true);
            monsterPositionY  += delta *.1f;
            monsterPositionX  -= delta *.1f;
        }if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)&& input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)){
            monster = monsterAnimationDown;
            monster.setPingPong(true);
            monsterPositionY  -= delta *.1f;
            monsterPositionX  += delta *.1f;
        }if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)&& input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)){
            monster = monsterAnimationDown;
            monster.setPingPong(true);
            monsterPositionY  -= delta *.1f;
            monsterPositionX  -= delta *.1f;
        }

    }
}
```

Could you provide a way to make the animation work please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to this method but maybe you have to [start the animation](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Animation.html#start%28%29).

Then, you should update your animation object by giving the delta in your update method.

In your `Play.update`:

```
  monster.update(delta);
```

Hope this helps